# The Cassandra Explorer cannot be connected when port is changed in BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

When I apply a port offset in repository/conf/carbon.xml file of WSO2 BAM, connecting to the Cassandra cluster is failed. Is this a known bug or should I change some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you enter the correct connection URL. The example URL next to the connection URL text box is correct only for the zero port offset BAM server. Add the port offset to the port number mentioned in the sample connection URL when entered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct Cassandra port if you have changed the port offset. New Cassandra port value will be (9160 + port offset). 
Hope this helps.